# OpenGL blending (Java)

Tags: java, opengl, colors, blending

I'm writing some Java OpenGL code (though the principles are the same in C++ openGL). I have a situation where I want to render certain items on top of others. I can do that by disable the depth test or by setting it to GL_ALWAYS) for those items and that works well. The issue is that colors of those items on top seem to be darkened by the items underneath it. I'm not sure if it's a lighting issue or if it's some blending issue but I'm trying to show the item's color without being affected by the colors around it, regardless of this item's z-position (since depth testing is set to ALWAYS). Is there a lighting setting or blending setting I should be using for this?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Two questions: do you mean that you want the thing drawn last to always be shown in a particular pixel, regardless of what was drawn before and regardless of depth; secondly are you sure you don't use transparency anywhere?

Comment: @DJClayworth, I want the last object drawn to be the one to show at a particular spot, correct, which is working well without the depth test. And, yes, I am not using transparency. When I rotate the scene, it looks correct though. Really I think need a two pass rendering where I render the base of the scene then a group of objects without a depth test and render that whole result on the base scene.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation, I'd leave the depth settings alone, but adjust the Z value of the objects based on the drawing order (for those items you want drawn based on order instead of normal depth).

```
glBegin(GL_WHATEVER);
    for (int i=0; i<num_objects; i++) 
        glVertex(object[i].x, object[i].y, i/-100.0f);
glEnd(GL_WHATEVER);
```

Comment: Thanks. In this application though, I am adding things to the surface of a globe and users can rotate the globe. If the z-values are changed, then the items won't actually be on the surface.